# Write Timeout error in Cassandra using python cassandra driver

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-python-driver

I have a single node cluster and when I perform the following query, I get the following error,

```
DELETE FROM issuetable WHERE "partitionId"='1';
```

**

- **Error**:

** :

```
WriteTimeout: Error from server: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed 
out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out 
- received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 
'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'QUORUM'}
```

As per datastax document (https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra.html), they mentioned increasing the `write_request_timeout_in_ms` in the `cassandra.yaml`

**Question** :

1) Why I get this error? As per my table (`issuetable`) I have only 84 entries under that partition.

2) Should this be solved client-side or server-side?

Comment: whats your replication factor, and how many nodes/dcs do you have? Looks like you have a RF < 3 so if the 1 node that owns the data is in a GC or something it will timeout.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink CREATE KEYSPACE issuekeyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'} AND durable_writes = true; so how to avoid this issue? Do I need to tune any parameter?

Comment: with a RF of one its same as using CL.ALL, that node has a GC and you will have timeouts. To have availability when a node is unavailable you need at least 3 replicas